# Is there an easier way to find the proportion of a factor that is a certain level by date?

Tags: r, group-by, factors

I have data composed of dates (which are all the first date of every month from 01/01/2008 to 12/01/2019) and a column of factors (either 0 or 1). I want to create a new dataset that has the proportion of 1's for each month.

I first split the data by date.

```
split_by_month=split(pre_polchangedata,as.Date(pre_polchangedata$ServiceDate)
```

I then have been creating new variables of the proportion of 1's per month manually, like so

```
Jan2008=split_by_month$'2008-01-01'
summary(Jan2008$FamilyRetentionFail)
0          1
12504    1367
```

Needless to say, this is a very slow process! Is there a faster way to do this?

I tried

```
pre_polchangedata %>*
group_by(ServiceDate)
mutate(Prop=sum(familyRetentionFail==1)/n()) %>%
```

but it just made the exact same dataframe I had before.

Comment: You need to assign `pre_polchangedata <-`. Also there is a typo `%>*` i.e. `pre_polchangedata <- pre_polchangedata %>% group_by(ServiceDate) %>% mutate(Prop = mean(familyRetentionFail == 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(familyRetentionFail~ServiceDate, pre_polchangedata,
           function(x) mean(x == 1))
```

If `familyRetentionFail` is numeric and has only 0 and 1 value the above could be simplified to :

```
aggregate(familyRetentionFail~ServiceDate, pre_polchangedata, mean)
```